# Copy only values to a different sheet not formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making an invoicing sheet. I want all the fields in the invoice to be copied and logged into a different sheet every time after a invoice is generated.

I have used multiple formulas in the invoice sheet and when i try and copy i am getting an error. How do i only copy values here?

Comment: Copy>Paste values only.

Comment: No, i dont mean that. I mean when i script through Google App Scripts

Comment: [Edit] to show your script then.

Comment: Post some of your code here or a brief explanation of what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values with formatting, use [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue).
If you just want the value of the cell, use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `getValues()` to copy data (this function ignores formulas and only copies the values) and `setValues()` to paste them in the invoice

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('123');
var data = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange('A1:A2').getValues();
ss.getSheetByName('invoice').getRange('A1:A2').setValues(data);
```